# Aggregating Tally counters

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Many times I find myself counting occurrences with `Tally[ ]` and then, once I discarded the original list, having to add (and join) to that counters list the results from another list.

This typically happens when I am counting configurations, occurrences, doing some discrete statistics, etc.

So I defined a very simple but handy function for Tally aggregation:

```
aggTally[listUnTallied__List:{}, 
         listUnTallied1_List,
         listTallied_List] := 
 Join[Tally@Join[listUnTallied, listUnTallied1], listTallied] //. 
     {a___, {x_, p_}, b___, {x_, q_}, c___} -> {a, {x, p + q}, b, c};
```

Such that

```
l = {x, y, z}; lt = Tally@l;
n = {x};
m = {x, y, t};

aggTally[n, {}]
  {{x, 1}}

aggTally[m, n, {}]
  {{x, 2}, {y, 1}, {t, 1}}

aggTally[m, n, lt]
  {{x, 3}, {y, 2}, {t, 1}, {z, 1}}
```

This function has two problems:

1) Performance

```
Timing[Fold[aggTally[Range@#2, #1] &, {}, Range[100]];]
  {23.656, Null}
(* functional equivalent to *)
Timing[s = {}; j = 1; While[j < 100, s = aggTally[Range@j, s]; j++]]
  {23.047, Null}
```

2) It does not validate that the last argument is a *real* Tallied list or null (less important for me, though)

Is there a simple, elegant, faster and more effective solution? (I understand that these are too many requirements, but wishing is free)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps, this will suit your needs?

```
aggTallyAlt[listUnTallied__List : {}, listUnTallied1_List, listTallied : {{_, _Integer} ...}] :=
{#[[1, 1]], Total@#[[All, 2]]} & /@ 
       GatherBy[Join[Tally@Join[listUnTallied, listUnTallied1], listTallied], First]
```

The timings are much better, and there is a pattern-based check on the last arg.

EDIT:

Here is a faster version:

```
aggTallyAlt1[listUnTallied__List : {}, listUnTallied1_List, listTallied : {{_, _Integer} ...}] :=
Transpose[{#[[All, 1, 1]], Total[#[[All, All, 2]], {2}]}] &@
   GatherBy[Join[Tally@Join[listUnTallied, listUnTallied1], listTallied], First]
```

The timings for it:

```
In[39]:= Timing[Fold[aggTallyAlt1[Range@#2, #1] &, {}, Range[100]];]
Timing[s = {}; j = 1; While[j < 100, s = aggTallyAlt1[Range@j, s]; j++]]

Out[39]= {0.015, Null}

Out[40]= {0.016, Null}
```

Comment: Your second version is VERY fast. It seems ReplaceRepeated[ ] should be used very carefully when performance is an issue.

Comment: Indeed, `ReplaceRepeated` should be used with care. I have a small section on this topic in my book: http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node355.html. To see some example where its performance is quite decent (due to usage of linked lists), you may want to look at e.g. this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/062e206f2372d899. So, it all depends on the pattern. Patterns with many blanks are usually inefficient when used with `ReplaceRepeated`.

Answer (score 5):

The following solution is just a small modification of your original function. It applies `Sort` before using `ReplaceRepeated` and can thus use a less general replacement pattern which makes it much faster:

```
aggTally[listUnTallied__List : {}, listUnTallied1_List, 
   listTallied : {{_, _Integer} ...}] := 
  Sort[Join[Tally@Join[listUnTallied, listUnTallied1], 
     listTallied]] //. {a___, {x_, p_}, {x_, q_}, c___} -> {a, {x, p + q}, c};
```

Comment: Although the performance is not comparable to those solutions without patterns, the improvement over my function is really impressive with such a little modification. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the fastest thing I've come up with yet, (ab)using the tagging available with `Sow` and `Reap`:

```
aggTally5[untallied___List, tallied_List: {}] :=
  Last[Reap[
    Scan[((Sow[#2, #] &) @@@ Tally[#]) &, {untallied}];
    Sow[#2, #] & @@@ tallied;
    , _, {#, Total[#2]} &]]
```

Not going to win any beauty contests, but it's all about speed, right? =)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't check why, but seems to fail with **aggTally2[m, n, lt]** (arguments in the question). Where have you been? We missed you! :)

Comment: Very, very busy, so I've been mostly lurking. I see that several of my colleagues are carrying the torch admirably though! I updated my answer with the right paste, but I realized it's not quite right...

Comment: Updated with a working solution, and faster all around to boot.

Answer (score 2):

If you stay purely symbolic, you may try something along the lines of

```
(Plus @@ Times @@@ Join[#1, #2] /. Plus -> List /. Times -> List) &
```

for joining tally lists. This is stupid fast but returns something that isn't a tally list, so it needs some work (after which it may not be so fast anymore ;) ).

EDIT: So I've got a working version:

```
aggT = Replace[(Plus @@ Times @@@ Join[#1, #2] 
                  /. Plus -> List 
                  /. Times[a_, b_] :> List[b, a]), 
                k_Symbol -> List[k, 1], {1}] &;
```

Using a couple of random symbolic tables I get

```
a := Tally@b;
b := Table[f[RandomInteger@99 + 1], {i, 100}];

Timing[Fold[aggT[#1, #2] &, a, Table[a, {i, 100}]];]
--> {0.104954, Null}
```

This version only adds tally lists, doesn't check anything, still returns some integers, and comparing to Leonid's function:

```
Timing[Fold[aggTallyAlt1[#2, #1] &, a, Table[b, {i, 100}]];]
--> {0.087039, Null}
```

it's already a couple of seconds slower :-(.

Oh well, nice try.

Comment: It seems to return inhomogeneous elements. Those having only one occurrence does not show the counter.

Comment: Uuh, well, like I said it's very rough around the edges. Mainly I just wanted to show off an outside the box idea. I'll see if I have time to play around with it some more, though Leonid seems to be on the ball.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! There are very good answers already. Anyway, I'll keep it open for a couple of days.